# Can a person confirm paternity by results of a DNA matching service to the father's distant relative?

Tags: birth-records, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis, myheritage.com, paternity

I am trying to find a way to confirm that the man listed on my birth certificate is my father or not (hopefully not). I have some obstacles, of course, one is that he died in 2011. We were not close (and not because of me) and I was not even mentioned in his obituary. We never took a DNA test. I recently found out that the two youngest of the three kids on his obituary are his step-children. The oldest child, however, I am not sure and I don't want to contact her without something to go on. Because my mother (d. 2016) had a habit of lying, I am no longer sure that man is my father. I have been on Ancestry.com and MyHeritage.com. No one with his surname has come up as a possible relative, however, there are two people that did come up recently (even though they have been on Ancestry.com for years; neither show up on My Heritage). One cousin (2nd-3rd) has my paternal grandmother's maiden name and we have 1% shared DNA | 93 cM across 6 segments. Another distant cousin (2nd-3rd) shares a surname with my father's half-sister (d. 2008) and we have 4% shared DNA | 304 cM across 15 segments, but I am not sure if that name is hers by marriage or not. I really don't want this man to be my father. I don't even really look like him. I suspect my father could be a former coworker of my mother's because I look like people in his family, but as far as I know, he is not related to the man on my birth certificate. I don't know if any of the second man's family is listed in my search. I don't want to contact him yet, either, until I have more to go on. Because my brother and my mother's sister come up as 1st cousins on Ancestry.com, I am not sure of the accuracy of these results.  I have left messages for both distant cousins, no reply yet.  Is it possible to be related to the cousins and not the man listed as my father on my bc? Is there another way to find out without contacting the family?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange!

I'm confused by your saying "my father's half-sister" and "paternal grandmother" when you are unsure who your father is. Can we assume you're referring to the man listed as your father on your birth certificate?

Comment: As for the Ancestry.com predicted relationship between your brother and your aunt, how many centiMorgans was the match? That is more useful than their guess that they are first cousins.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the man who is on my birth certificate.

Comment: Everett B. 2nd – 3rd Cousin 93 cM | 1% shared DNA

Comment: Letishia R. 2nd – 3rd Cousin 304 cM | 4% shared DNA (she may be my "father's" half-sister's daughter). Also another cousin possible related to my paternal "grandmother" - eburganjr214 3rd – 4th Cousin 71 cM | 1% shared DNA.

Comment: I do not know any of these people and my grandparents and parents (and aunts/uncles) are all deceased.

Comment: @brownin329 I had to delete the comment containing names as our privacy policy states that identifying information about potentially living people cannot be posted. You are fine to identify any deceased ancestors but living people should not be mentioned by name.